# ES6 promises with timeout interval

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying to convert some of my code to promises, but I can't figure out how to chain a new promise inside a promise.

My promise function should check the content of an array every second or so, and if there is any item inside it should resolve. Otherwise it should wait 1s and check again and so on.

```
function get(){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {

      if(c.length > 0){
        resolve(c.shift());

      }else{
        setTimeout(get.bind(this), 1000);
      }

    });

}


let c = [];

setTimeout(function(){
  c.push('test');
}, 2000);
```

This is how I expect my get() promise function to work, it should print "test" after 2 or 3 seconds max:

```
get().then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Obviously it doesn't work, nothing is ever printed

Answer (score 4):

`setTimeout` has terrible chaining and error-handling characteristics on its own, so always [wrap it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Creating_a_Promise_around_an_old_callback_API):

```js
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

function get(c) {
  if (c.length) {
    return Promise.resolve(c.shift());
  }
  return wait(1000).then(() => get(c)); // try again
}

let c = [];
get(c).then(val => console.log(val));
wait(2000).then(() => c.push('test'));
```

While you didn't ask, for the benefit of others, this is a great case where `async`/`await` shines:

```js
const wait = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

async function get(c) {
  while (!c.length) {
    await wait(1000);
  }
  return c.shift();
}

let c = [];
get(c).then(val => console.log(val));
wait(2000).then(() => c.push('test'));
```

Note how we didn't need `Promise.resolve()` this time, since `async` functions do this implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your recursive call doesn't pass the `resolve` function along, so the `else` branch can never call `resolve`.

One way to fix this would be to create a closure inside the promise's callback so that the recursive call will have access to the same `resolve` variable as the initial call to `get`.

```js
function get() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    function loop() {
      if (c.length > 0) {
        resolve(c.shift());
      } else {
        setTimeout(loop, 1000);
      }
    }
    loop();
  });
}

let c = [];
setTimeout(function() {
  c.push('test');
}, 2000);
get().then(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: What happens is `c` isn't empty? I don't think what he wants is possible from a single Promise.

Comment: @Mark_M If `c` isn't empty, it will immediately `resolve` with the first value in `c`.

Comment: The way I read the question was that he wants to continue checking after that.

Comment: @Mark_M What part of the question makes you think that? A promise can only resolve one time, so any subsequent calls to `resolve` would be ignored.

Comment: Yes, I understand, that's why I thought it wasn't possible. I suppose the reason I read it this ways that there's little reason to go through all this to just return a single value … and also the '…and so on'. I certainly could have misread it.

Answer (score 0):

In the `else` case, you never resolve *that* promise. `get` might create another one, but it is returned to nowhere.

You should [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) your asynchronous function (`setTimeout`) on the lowest level, and then only chain your promises. By `return`ing the result of the recursive call from a `then` callback, the resulting promise will resolve with the same result:

```
function delayAsync(time) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, time);
    });
}
function get(c) {
    if (c.length > 0){
        return Promise.resolve(c.shift());
    } else {
        return delay(1000).then(() => {
            return get(c); // try again
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a polling service, which checks periodically for specific condition prior proceeding with promise resolution. Currently when you run `setTimeout(get.bind(this), 1000);` you are creating a new instance of the promise without actually resolving the initial promise, because you don't reference to the initial `resolve` function that you created.

Solution:

- Create a new callback function that you can reference to it inside the promise
- Pass the `resolve` & `reject` as params in the setTimeout invocation e.g. `setTimeout(HandlePromise, 1000, resolve, reject, param3, param4 ..);`  [setTimeout API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

```js
function get() {
  var handlerFunction = resolve => {
    if (c.length > 0) {
      resolve(c.shift());
    } else {
      setTimeout(handlerFunction, 1000, resolve);
    }
  };

  return new Promise(handlerFunction);
}

let c = [];

setTimeout(function() {
  c.push("test");
}, 2000);

get().then(value => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

- For more information look into [javascript polling article](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-polling)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this solution. Since JS needs to free itself to download the images, I use await within an asynchronous function and an asynchronous call to wake up JS after a delay

```
private async onBeforeDoingSomething() : void {
    await this.delay(1000);
    console.log("All images are loaded");    
} 

private delay (ms : number = 500) : Promise<number> {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        const t = setTimeout( () => this.areImgsLoaded(resolve), ms);
    });
} 

private async areImgsLoaded (resolve) {
    let reload = false;
    const img = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    console.log("total of images: ",img.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++){
        if (!img[i]["complete"]) {
            console.log("img not load yet");
            reload = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (reload) {
        await this.delay();
    }
    resolve();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `setInterval` to check every second. Run this script to understand.

```js
let c = [];

function get(){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {

      var i = setInterval(function(){
        if(c.length > 0){
          resolve(c.shift());
          clearInterval(i);
        }
      }, 1000);

    });
}



setTimeout(function(){
  c.push('test');
}, 2000);

get().then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: You should also provide a way to remove interval once it is resolved. Otherwise, the callback will keep running infinitely.